# jQuery UI Draggable animation whilst snapping to a grid

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-draggable

jQuery UI Draggable offers a `grid` option which, when set, will snap your draggable element to a grid. The only problem I'm having with this is I still want it to animate before snapping.

If my grid is `[500,500]` then there will be no user feedback until the mouse covers a distance of 500px.

Is it possible to do a similar "snap to grid" thing but also animate at the same time?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I presume you mean you want to snap to a grid after the user has finished dragging. In this case, you can make use of the draggable's `stop` event and calculate the element's offset.

Assume you have a draggable contained within a parent element, starting at offset (0, 0), which is the top-left hand corner. You then apply a regular draggable effect to the element, and on `stop` you calculate its position and snap it to the nearest "cell".

The code for this would look something like:

```
$(el).draggable({
  stop: function(e, ui) {
    var elem = ui.helper,
        left = elem.position().left,
        top  = elem.position().top;

    elem.css({
      left: left - (left%10),
      top: top - (top%10)
    });
  }
});
```

This code will always snap based on the element's top-left pixel co-ordinate, and relies on the element being absolutely positioned and the parent being non-statically positioned (relative, absolute, etc.)

** Edit **

I have created a quick demo - http://jsfiddle.net/LQwMe/1/

Comment: Perfect! That's exactly what I was looking for. One question: what does `left%20` do?

Comment: It's a modulo operation that calculates the remainder left by the division. So if `left` is 104, `left%20` would equal 4.

Comment: Thanks, but why would you need the remainder?

Comment: To work out how far you are from the snap-point. If your grid is 100x100, and each cell is 20x20, there are 5 cells across and 5 cells down. If the draggable is dragged to (67, 46), the nearest snap-point is at (60, 40), so you need to work out how far beyond you are and compensate.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. Wht if my grid was 960x150 high though? How would I calculate something like that using a modulo operation?

Comment: You need to visualise it as a grid of cells: you are snapping the element to the top-left of the nearest cell. If you want to snap the element in increments of 20px, then each cell is 20x20. This is the figure you use in the modulo operation. I've created an example with a literal grid so you can see the concept - http://jsfiddle.net/d5kj9/

Comment: Also, is it possible to do it the other way, so if the draggable is dragged to (67, 46) it would be closer to (70, 50) so it would go right and down to that as opposed to left and up to (60, 40)?

Comment: Yep; if you want to snap the bottom right corner, you would do something like `left%20 >= 5 ? left - (left%20) + 20 : left - (left%20)`. This would snap the frame to the corner it's closer to.

Comment: Add this css rules to get a smooth animation at the end of dragging. 
```ui-draggable:not(.ui-draggable-dragging) {
     transition:all 0.3s ease;
   }
```